# ionic 2 ion-grid / ion-row / ion-col not working when used as a attribute to div

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, grid-layout

```
<ion-grid no-padding>
    <ion-row>
        <ion-col>col 1</ion-col>
        <ion-col>col 2</ion-col>
        <ion-col>col 3</ion-col>
    </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

Above code works good, its respective styles are applied, but, below one doesn't work.

```
<div ion-grid>
    <div ion-row>
        <div ion-col>col 1 div</div>
        <div ion-col>col 2 div</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I tried to put it as attributes, styles are not applied for grid, I get something similar to

col 1 div

col 2 div

expected result: col 1 div     col 2 div

What am I doing wrong?

ref: http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/grid/Grid/#grid-size

Comment: The styles are applied to the tag names, so if you use divs ionic css style rules won't be applied. May I ask why would you use a div instead of ionic tags (ion-row, ion-col, ...)?

Comment: Yeah may be that is the reason, but, in documentation it is supported. Was migrating from ionic 1, so thought it would be easy to use existing components with attributes. Also want to know if I have missed any setting for these kind of feature.

Comment: Hmmm as far as I know, docs don't say anything about using ion-row and ion-col as attributes, they're html elements...

Comment: It is referred at only one place in grid docs .. Please check below link ..  http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/grid/Grid/#how-it-works

Comment: You're absolutely right, for some reason I was being able to see the old Grid docs page instead of the new one :S